# splits the hunk in ediff mode

Tags: ediff, diff-mode

Is splitting the hunk in ediff mode possible?

> diff-mode provides diff-split-hunk which splits the hunk at the current line. You can then apply, or reverse it with (C-u) diff-apply-hunk. Can be very convenient for selectively applying/undoing changes.

Hope that's possible in ediff mode as well.